# Wpf Grid column shouldn't stretch according to its child item

Tags: wpf, listview

In normal circumstances Grid column is obeying its defined width(via ColumnDefinition).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="Column1Value Column1Value Column1Value" Background="Red"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Column2Value" Background="Yellow"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Text="Column3Value" Background="Green"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="Column1Value Column1Value Column1Value" Background="Red"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Column2Value" Background="Yellow"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Text="Column3Value" Background="Green"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: Text]

Column-0 content is clipped to obey grid width definition.
Everything is perfect so far.

But If I use Grid inside a ListView as an ItemTemplate like below

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type system:String}">
            <system:String>DemoPurposeItem1</system:String>
            <system:String>DemoPurposeItem2</system:String>
        </x:Array>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Column1Value Column1Value Column1Value" Background="Red"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Column2Value" Background="Yellow"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Column3Value" Background="Green"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

[image: Text]

Column-0 content is **not clipped**. Column-0 start to stretch according to its content.

Why Grid behave differently when its used inside ListView. I want my Grid to obey its defined width(2*).

Note: I have to use Grid as ItemTemplate for ListView, I couldn't change this structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why Grid behave differently when its used inside ListView.

Because the space that is available to the `Grid` in the template is infinite by default.

If you set the `Width` of the inner `Grid`, the star-sizing will work as expected.

You could for example set it to the `Width` of the `ListView` using a binding:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid Width="{Binding ActualWidth,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Column1Value Column1Value Column1Value" Background="Red"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Column2Value" Background="Yellow"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="Column3Value" Background="Green"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

You may want to use a converter to decrease that width a bit. Anyway, the key here is to somehow contraint the available width.